# Cannot mount RAID 5 array on server, "Unable to read superblock"

Tags: linux, ext4, raid5, file-server, e2fsck

I am an novice to servers and RAID arrays, but I am trying to restore a raid 5 array that has recently started to have problems with mounting onto our server. Full disclosure, I was not the one who originally set up this array. I am working with a Dell 2950 PowerEdge server that we have installed CentOS 7 on to manage programs and files. My issue began when I couldn't start up the server after a restart. My current set up tries to mount the array when the main server is started up. The command in /etc/fstab currently is commented out on bootup of our server because it causes the server to crash on start up. When the server is started, we uncomment out the line

```
/dev/sdc  /array   ext4   defaults    1 2
```

Then when I try and mount with:

```
mount /array
```

I get the following:

```
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdc,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error

       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail or so.
```

Tailing the dmesg:

```
[1625373.377926] sd 1:2:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK cmd_age=0s
[1625373.377929] sd 1:2:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 CDB: Read(16) 88 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 08 00 00
[1625373.377931] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdc, sector 0
[1625373.377933] Buffer I/O error on dev sdc, logical block 0, async page read
[1633765.092732] nf_conntrack: falling back to vmalloc.
[1633765.093244] nf_conntrack: falling back to vmalloc.
[1633782.909748] sd 1:2:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK cmd_age=0s
[1633782.909757] sd 1:2:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 CDB: Read(16) 88 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 02 00 00 00 02 00 00
[1633782.909761] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdc, sector 2
[1633782.909782] EXT4-fs (sdc): unable to read superblock
```

It appears that there is a bad superblock. I am not sure where to even begin on how to approach fixing this issue. I don't want to reformat the entire array at loss of the data (over 10 TB) if I can avoid it.
Some other helpful information might be that this is not a MD compatible server (might be obvious, wasn't to me initially) so `mdadm` commands are not applicable.
It is set up with a EXT4 file system.
The array was also not likely properly partitioned when it was initialized 5+ years ago, i.e., there is no sdc0, sdc1, etc. I am not sure as to the full ramifications of that might have, but it sounds like certain functions/scripts will assume that the array is properly partitioned and can cause things to get "hairy" if used improperly.
Any help with this issue would be greatly appreciated. If there is information that I am not providing that would help in diagnosing the issue, please let me know.

Update: I wanted to see if I could find which superblock was having trouble. With the array unmounted, I tried the following:
`$ dumpe2fs /dev/sdc | grep -i superblock`
output from that command gave me:

```
dumpe2fs 1.42.9 (28-Dec-2013)
dumpe2fs: Attempt to read block from filesystem resulted in short read while trying to open /dev/sdc
Couldn't find valid filesystem superblock.
```

I also tried running `mke2fs -n /dev/sdc` to try and see if I could get more information on the Superblocks. this was the results

```
# mke2fs -n /dev/sdc
mke2fs 1.42.9 (28-Dec-2013)
/dev/sdc is entire device, not just one partition!
Proceed anyway? (y,n) y
Filesystem label=
OS type: Linux
Block size=4096 (log=2)
Fragment size=4096 (log=2)
Stride=0 blocks, Stripe width=0 blocks
335577088 inodes, 2684616704 blocks
134230835 blocks (5.00%) reserved for the super user
First data block=0
Maximum filesystem blocks=4294967296
81928 block groups
32768 blocks per group, 32768 fragments per group
4096 inodes per group
Superblock backups stored on blocks: 
        32768, 98304, 163840, 229376, 294912, 819200, 884736, 1605632, 2654208, 
        4096000, 7962624, 11239424, 20480000, 23887872, 71663616, 78675968, 
        102400000, 214990848, 512000000, 550731776, 644972544, 1934917632, 
        2560000000
```

Update (2022-11-15)

I was able to get some assistance from our IT team and we were able to get into the BIOS for our server. It might be helpful to know our raid 5 was a PERC 5/E, and in the BIOS we found that the slot 8 disk was considered "foreign". We "import"ed (NOT "clear") the disk in slot 8 and the array came back up, but in a degraded state.
Odd thing was that our disk in slot 0 was marked as "missing" which was odd. I believe that there was a disk inserted into the array as a global hot spare, and I think that it was used by the array to maintain parody.
To ensure we don't lose the data, I am backing up the array on the external 15 TB drive with "rsync" before trying to figure out how to reestablish the global hot spare. Fingers crossed the copy process goes smoothly. Thanks everyone for all the help!

Comment: What does `fdisk -l /dev/sdc` return, if anything? In other words are you really sure that there's a filesystem but no partition table on the disk?

Comment: The output from ```fdisk -l /dev/sdc``` returned the following:
     
$ fdisk -l /dev/sdc
fdisk: cannot open /dev/sdc: Input/output error

Comment: Mmm I thought it might. Oh well. You need to revert to the BIOS setup and find out why your (hardware) array is failing

Answer (score 1):

> /dev/sdc

hmmmm.

So this is hardware RAID. The first place you *should* have been looking was in the controller at boot time. It is also possible to configure the device while Linux is running on the computer - but you need some rather esoteric software for this. This is probably a DELL Perc 5i or 6i. With this being a very old computer the software might not be available for Ubuntu/Debian - you'll need to scout the internet for the right software.

That it has previously been provisioned without any partitioning is odd.

You didn't say what happened after you wiped the drive - it seems to be reporting success. Even if it is now apparently working I would still want to rebuild the array from the controller, run badblocks against it, partition it then create a new filesystem.

Comment: I've done diags and config on PERC cards via the BIOS interface.  It's not a lot of fun, but it's possible.  If the card supports it, of course.

Answer (score 1):

**If the data is VERY important, then I would:**

1. Get a separate storage device big enough to contain (an image of) the entire contents of /dev/sdc. (RAID array size * 1.15)
2. Dump the entire RAID as a block level image file onto that separate device. (Using dd for example)
3. Any attempts at data recovery, FS repairs, mounting, data carving, etc. can now safely be done to that image instead of endangering data on the physical RAID array.
4. Keep the physical RAID in it's current state in case you screw something up and need to dump a new image.

**Any data copied/carved/extracted from the image should be saved to a third storage device.**

---

**Minimalistic Example:**

To dump the RAID as an image file you first have to mount the device(partition) you want it saved to.

```bash
sudo mkdir /mnt/imgfiles
sudo mount /dev/sdd2 /mnt/imgfiles
```

Then use **dd** to dump the raw array data to an image.

```bash
sudo dd if=/dev/sdc of=/mnt/imgfiles/array_raw.img
```

**NOTE:**  This command does not report progress unless that specific option (which I don'remember) is added to the command line.

**NOTE2:**  This WILL take a long time. Hard drives are slow and it's a LOT of data.

Comment: If it is very important there should be backups

Comment: @roaima yeah. **should** is the word.

Comment: @svin83, thanks for your input. I just want to make sure that I do this correctly, since as I've been reading, it appears DD can potentially destroy data if used improperly. for the "block size [bs=]" wouldn't that need to be `bs=4096` to match that of `mke2fs -n /dev/sdc` output? Also you mention dumping as an image file. Does that mean *.img style file? if you could give an example of how to create this image using DD, that would be really helpful.

Comment: My initial thought is something along the line of `sudo dd if=/dev/sdc of=/dev/sdd2/array1_backup.img bs=4096 conv=sync,noerror`

Comment: @Schmidt NO!  /dev/sdd2 is not a directory. It is a *file* representing **partition number 2** on **block device sdd!**  It must be mounted in a directory if you want filesystem access (read and/or write access to files).

Comment: @Schmidt I judt added an example. It is a bit sparse but should result in a complete dump to a raw image file.

Answer (score 0):

The errors reported by dmesg on the console and by dumpe2fs indicate that this is a problem with the RAID array itself, and not the filesystem.

The first thing you will likely need to do is (somehow) poke at the RAID array to determine if it has multiple failing disks, or needs some sort of reset. How to do that is specific to the Dell hardware.

As @svin83 commented, being able to copy /dev/sdc to another backup device with "`ddrescue`" or "`dd if=/dev/sdc of=/dev/XXX bs=1M conv=sync,noerror`" is a good way to ensure that the device is at least mostly working, and avoids Oh $#!+ moments if you make a mistake with something else.  The whole array is under 11TB, so for a few hundred dollars you could buy a single 12/14TB SATA3 drive that is large enough to make a full backup.

That there is no partition table is not so unusual for hardware RAID, to avoid alignment issues.

Comment: and @svin83, thanks for your comments. We actually purchased a 15 TB WD external drive and I used DiskGenius on a windows machine to partition that external drive with a EXT4 file system because we intended to back the system up, with just a simple rsync to the new drive. We were making plans to move this data to the cloud as well. 
As for dd, would something like this work?
`dd if/dev/sdc of=/dev/sdd2 bs=1M conv=sync,noerror`?

Comment: here is the output from `lsblk` for the external drive:

`sdd                      8:48   0  14.6T  0 disk`
      `|-sdd1                   8:49   0   200M  0 part` 
      `-sdd2                   8:50   0  14.6T  0 part /run/media/home/Expansion`
My concern is I'd read somewhere that to use ddrescue and similar scripts requires the external drive to be not partitioned (unallocated space). Is that right?

Comment: Poking around a bit more, it looks like `ddrescue` might be a better option here (possibly). I have the 15 TB drive but it's already partitioned, but it has over 14.6 TB of space. it looks like I should be able to save an image of the 10 TB array on the drive if I run something like this:    `ddrescue -d -r1 /dev/sdc /run/media/[USER]/Expansion/array1/array1_img.raw array1clone.log`.  The `-d` flag bypassing the linux kernal cache, and `-r1` so that if it fails to read some data, it doesn't keep trying. Does this seem reasonable?